# React Native Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.camera.capture')

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

```
export class CameraView extends Component {
render(){
    return(
        <View style={{
                flex: 1,
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
            }}>
            <Camera
                ref={(cam) => {
                    this.camera = cam;
                }}
                style={styles.preview}
                aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}>
                <CaptureControls></CaptureControls>
                <Image></Image>
            </Camera>
        </View>
    );
  }
}


export class CaptureControls extends Component {
render(){
    return(
        <View style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                bottom: 30,
            }}>
            <Image style={{
                    width: 30,
                    height: 30,
                    marginRight: 75,
                }} source={require('img/opengallery.png')}></Image>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}>
                <Image style={{
                        width: 70,
                        height: 70,
                    }} source={require('img/takepicture.png')}> </Image>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <Image style={{
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                        marginLeft: 75,
                }} source={require('img/switchcam.png')}></Image>
        </View>
    );
}
takePicture() {
    this.camera.capture()
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
}
```

Here's my code. When pressing the takepicture button I get undefined is not an object. What is wrong with my code? takePicture() worked on a Text element though. I added a TouchableHighlight around the Image and added the onPress to TouchableHighlight, but now it crashes.

Kind regards,
Matthew

Answer (score 0):

I guess you figured this out in the meantime. The 'camera' variable is assigned in the context of CameraView but the code tries to access it from within CaptureControls.